# Aren't pull-up / pull-down options documented for STM32F103?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32f10x, st, cmsis

While trying to configure the GPIOs using CMSIS on a [NUCLEO-F103RB](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f103rb.html) board, I couldn't seem to find in the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf) how one is supposed to choose between internal pull-up and pull-down resistors.

Page 160 shows the configuration of the CNF and MODE bits and shows that the bits are the same for pull-up and pull-down. Searching the entire PDF file for "pull-up" and "pull-down" yields no results. [The errata](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/7d/02/75/64/17/fc/4d/fd/CD00190234.pdf/files/CD00190234.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00190234.pdf) also has no mention of this.

Did ST **seriously** forget to put this information in the manual? If so, how come no one has noticed this? Or am I just being blind?

Anyway, looking at their standard peripheral library, it seems that writing a 1 to the corresponding bit in the GPIO BRR register activates the pull-down resistor, while writing a 1 to the BSRR actives the pull-up resistor:

```
    /* Reset the corresponding ODR bit */
    if (GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode == GPIO_Mode_IPD)
    {
      GPIOx->BRR = (((uint32_t)0x01) << pinpos);
    }
    else
    {
      /* Set the corresponding ODR bit */
      if (GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode == GPIO_Mode_IPU)
      {
        GPIOx->BSRR = (((uint32_t)0x01) << pinpos);
      }
    }
```

This code can be found in the stm32f10x_gpio.c file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The information you are looking for is in the manual, but not as obvious as it could be.  The table you mentioned on page 160 contains more info:

[image: gpio]

As you can see, assuming the pin is configured as an input, the value in the ODR registers is the deciding factor as to whether the pin is pull-up or pull-down.

You can set and/or clear all these bits at once by writing a 16-bit value to the appropriate GPIOx_ODR register, or you can set/reset them individually by using the GPIOx_BRR and/or GPIOx_BSRR registers.

Interestingly, the same ODR register controls the pin state (high or low) when the pin is configured as an output.

I've found that I can sometimes learn more about the workings of the STM ARM controllers by reading through their Standard Peripheral Libraries than their reference manuals!

Comment: I like how it was right in front of my eyes and even though I looked at that table so many times I still couldn't see it. *facepalm*. Thank you.

Comment: @Chi Ha! That happens to me more than I like to admit :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi the information from the pull-up input configured is here
check this
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwAT3.png]

[image]

The configuration could be:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"              // Declaracion del Header
#define Clk_A   2

int main (){
RCC->APB2ENR|=(1<<Clk_A);       // Enable Clock to GPIOA
GPIOA->CRL=0x22220000;          // GPIO->A0:A3,Out A4:A7,in
GPIOA->CRL=0x22220000;          // GPIO->A7:A4,Out A3:A0,in
GPIOA->CRL|=0x8888;             // Pull-UP input A0:A3
GPIOA->ODR|=0x0F;               // Enable Pull UP A0:A3
while (1){
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Criss. I see you are new to the electrical engineering stack exchange, welcome :) Thank you for your answer but... this one has already been (correctly) answered almost 6 years ago. If you are unsure how stack exchange works, you can read the tour guide available here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour